# Unmatched ''"' when when decoding 'string' error in reading json file into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to load a amazon review data into pandas dataframe, which is a JSON file , using the pd.read_json(), I am getting the following error `Unmatched ''"' when when decoding 'string'.` I am using jupyter notebook

Data format:

```
{"reviewerID": "AGL65XWV7MH3C", "asin": "B003FMUVKO", "reviewerName": "William B. Bebout \"Acknud\"", "helpful": [0, 1], "reviewText": "Too short. I would have rated it higher if it was long enough to hold my attention! It did have significant violence but not much else.", "overall": 3.0, "summary": "Short", "unixReviewTime": 1304985600, "reviewTime": "05 10, 2011"}
```

Python code:

```
data =pd.read_json('sample_data.json', lines=True)
```

Comment: @GeneBurinsky: How to I reformat it?, And I have just shown one line of data, In my actual file I have 1000's of rows

Comment: Your code works fine on my laptop

Comment: Could it be that you're missing en escaping for your backslash? try replacing all "\" with "\\".

Comment: I executed the same code with less number of rows, And it worked for me,

Comment: is this a data error, or there is a way to solve it using the json.load() parameters ?. I'm having the same error.

Comment: in my case it just hadn't downloaded the full file for some reason so `read_json()` raised this error

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same error and after trying every possible solution the simple fix was to remove the empty line at the end of the file.

Leaving an empty line at the end of a file is a common convention but seems to choke pandas for some reason,

Answer (score 0):

Load the entire dataset into memory

import pandas as pd

## Assuming the data is in a file named "data.json"

df = pd.read_json("data.json", lines=True)

## Check the contents of the DataFrame

print(df.head())

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).