# 1TB json using Pandas json reader with Error "Unmatched ''"' when when decoding 'string'"

Tags: pandas, dataframe

The json file is 1TB. So I used `pandas.read_json` with `chunk_size=1000`.

When I get the `50,000,000`th chunk, it says `"Unmatched ''"' when when decoding 'string'"`. Obviously, I cannot do as [Unmatched ''"' when when decoding 'string' error in reading json file into pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50082528/unmatched-when-when-decoding-string-error-in-reading-json-file-into-panda) suggested.

How to deal with this issue, if I cannot, How to skip this chunk and resume from `50,000,001st` chunk. It seems that `pandas.io.json._json.JsonReader` is not iteratable.
Any idea? thx.

Comment: Your JSON file is broken, and that's not an easy thing to recover from in any case. As an aside, why would it be OK for your application to just skip a chunk of data? That sounds like it'll bite you later.